# RecyclerView in RecyclerView: ItemDecoration

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm using a `recyclerview` (with a vertical `LinearLayout`) with different `viewholders`, one of them has another `RecyclerView` (with an horizontal LL). In this second `recyclerView` I'm using an `ItemDecoration` to add a left margin to all of its items but the first.

The code in `onBindViewHolder` of the first `RecyclerView` related to my problem is:

```
RecyclerView mRecyclerView = holder.mRecyclerView;
mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new SpaceLeftItemDecoration(5));
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(mDataSet, context));
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
```

Everytime this code is executed, a new ItemDecorations is added to the recyclerview. If I scroll up and down 3 or 4 times, the spacing between items in the second recyclerview is really noticeable.

So my question is, how can I know if the `RecyclerView` already has an `ItemDecoration`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, move this code to `createViewHolder`, so it will be called only once.